# NGINX config always falls back into default location

Tags: nginx

I have the following NGINX (1.13) configuration in Docker container, that serves as an umbrella proxy for both frontend and backend. Server `backend` is PHP-FPM container and `frontend` is a NodeJS/React App.

I want the domain URL `http://example.com/.*` was caught by frontend and `http://example.com/api/.*` to be delivered to `backend`. Whatever I tried doesn't seem to work, and all API calls end up with 404 and being handled by `frontend`.

```
upstream api_cluster {
    server backend:8999;
}

server {
listen 80;
server_name localhost;
root /var/www/html;

location ~* ^/api/ {
  # handle OPTIONS requests
  # @note: don't try to DRY out this "if" block, or you're gonna have a bad time.
  # @see: http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil
  if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     'Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     'GET, DELETE, OPTIONS, POST, PUT';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age'           2592000;
    add_header 'Content-Length'                   0;
    add_header 'Content-Type'                     'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
    return 204;
  }

  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
  rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

  # send the CORS headers
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      '*';

  # set additional security headers
  add_header 'Cache-Control'                    'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate';
  #add_header 'Content-Security-Policy'          'connect-src *';
  add_header 'Expires'                          '0';
  add_header 'Pragma'                           'no-cache';
  add_header 'Strict-Transport-Security'        'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains';
  add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options'           'nosniff';
  add_header 'X-Frame-Options'                  'DENY';
  add_header 'X-XSS-Protection'                 '1; mode=block';


  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME       $fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO         $fastcgi_path_info;
  fastcgi_param   AUTHORIZATION     $http_authorization;
  # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
  fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_pass api_cluster;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use just `location /api` as the block directive, since you want a simple prefix match.

If changing this doesn't help, you need to verify that nginx actually uses the configuration you have created by running `nginx -T`, which displays the configuration nginx has parsed from configuration files.

Comment: that didn't help - and yes, the configuration file gets loaded in the container.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is a line `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` which internally makes a redirection to `/index.php?$args;`, which will match `location /`.

I shall thank user `xavierg` on NGINX IRC channel, who enlightened me on this and solved the problem.